# Will window.close work only work if the window shares a domain with the window trying to close it?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand when `window.close()` will / won't work. I know there are some requirements around the window being script closeable etc., but it seems like there are some additional requirements that I can't find formally laid out (at least, not laid out in terms I can't understand with my current javascript knowledge.)

At a high level, my use case is as follows:

- a user clicks a button
- I do some stuff and then do something like `windowRef = window.open("http://example.com/somedocument.pdf","popup")`.
- Once the user takes clicks a different button, I want to be able to call `windowRef.close()` and have it close the pdf I opened in a popup.

My current implementation works as long as the url I'm opening shares a domain with the window that's trying to close it, and not otherwise. That's fine (I can guarantee the PDF will come from the same domain as the window trying to close it) but I'd like to understand why this doesn't work for URLs with different domains (and if there are other cases where it won't work that I haven't run into yet).

Based on some experimenting in my application / the browser console, it seems like `window.close()` will work if the url I'm opening shares a domain with the window I'm trying to close it from, but not otherwise. That's purely based on testing / guessing though, I haven't found documentation explaining why this might be the case.

I've read the MDN documentation for window.close, but I can't seem to find it documented when exactly this function will work, and when it will just return "undefined" (but not log an error like "Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.)

I thought this might have to do with the Same-origin policy, but that article calls out `window.close()` as not having the same-origin requirement, and some tests I ran seem to confirm this.

Can someone explain to me what needs to be true for me to be confident that, if I'm opening a pdf in a popup window using `window.open()` to send a window to a URL to the pdf, I can later close that popup with `window.close()`

Comment: It is supposed to work even for cross-origin documents, as long as you didn't pass the `"noopener"` option to `open()`, but if you did you shouldn't have access to the proxy anyway. So that sounds like a bug in your browser, probably in their pdf reader plugin. Could you tell us more about which browser you're using?